# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{(x+1)^{1/x}}-(x+1)^{e/x}}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

By L'Hôpital's rule, it gets $$\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{\left(e^{(x+1)^{1/x}} (x+1)^{1/x}-e (x+1)^{e/x}\right) ((x+1) \log (x+1)-x)}{2x^3(1+x)},$$which becomes more complicated.

What could I do then?

Comment: your L Hospitals rule seems incorrect

Comment: apply individually on numerator and denominator

Comment: You are going to have to split the limit into the limit of the numerator and the limit of the denominator.  Also, given your exponent involves x, you'll need logarithmic differentiation...

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I now try again.

Comment: em...I've tried again with my classmate and both of us got the same result.  Then I verify it [online](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=e%5E%281%2Bx%29%5E%281%2Fx%29-%281%2Bx%29%5E%28e%2Fx%29), which is actually true. Maybe it's because I simplified the fraction.

Comment: That's a really tricky limit. +1 As usual a direct application of L'Hospital's Rule complicates things and one needs a reasonable amount of manipulation before application of L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numerator is of the form $a-b$ where $a, b$ both tend to $e^e$. It can be rewritten as $$b\cdot\frac{\exp(\log (a/b)) - 1}{\log(a/b)}\cdot \log(a/b) $$ and the fraction in middle tends to $1$ (because $a/b\to 1$) and hence the desired limit is equal to the limit of expression $$e^e\cdot\frac{\log a - \log b} {x^2}$$ or $$e^e\cdot\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/x}-\dfrac{e}{x}\log(1+x)} {x^2}$$ Applying the same process again (numerator in form $a-b$ with $a, b$ tending to same number $e$ here) we can see that the desired limit is equal to the limit of $$e^e\cdot e\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}-1-\log\left(\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right)} {x^2}\tag{1}$$ This limit can now be evaluated via Taylor series without much effort. We have $$\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^2)$$ and the logarithm of the above series is $$-\frac{x} {2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^2}{8}+o(x^2)$$ Thus the desired limit is $e^{e+1}/8$.

---

On a second thought the evaluation of limit of expression $(1)$ can be greatly simplified (and one can also use L'Hospital's Rule) after some manipulation. Barring the constant factor $e^{e+1} $ the fraction in $(1)$ can be written as $$\frac{u-\log(1+u)}{u^2}\cdot\left(\frac{u}{x}\right)^2\tag{2}$$ where $$u=\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x}\to 0$$ as $x\to 0$ and by L'Hospital's Rule the first fraction in $(2)$ tends to $1/2$ and $u/x\to - 1/2$ so that the expression in $(2)$ tends to $1/8$. Thus the complicated limit is handled using just a single application of L'Hospital's Rule. The same conclusion can be reached via Taylor series without any computation of coefficients.

Comment: Really nice way!

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\frac1x \log (1+x)}=e^{1-\frac12 x+\frac13x^2+o(x^2)}=e \cdot e^{-\frac12 x+\frac13x^2+o(x^2)}=e\left(1-\frac 1 2 x+\frac 1 3 x^2 +\frac12\left(-\frac12 x+\frac13x^2\right)^2+ o(x^2)\right)
=e\left(1-\frac 1 2 x+\frac{11}{24}x^2+o(x^2)\right)$$

$$e^{{(x+1)}^{\frac{1}{x}}}=e^{e}e^{-\frac e 2 x+\frac{11e}{24}x^2+o(x^2)}=e^{e}\left(1-\frac e 2 x+\frac{11e}{24}x^2+\frac{e^2}{8}x^2+o(x^2)\right)$$

and

$$(x+1)^{\frac{e}{x}}=e^{\frac e x \log (1+x)}=e^{e-\frac e 2 x+\frac e3x^2+o(x^2)}=e^ee^{-\frac e 2 x+\frac e3x^2+o(x^2)}=e^e\left(1-\frac e 2 x+\frac e3x^2+\frac {e^2}{8}x^2+o(x^2)\right)$$

and thus

$$\dfrac{e^{(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}}-(x+1)^{\frac{e}{x}}}{x^2}=\frac{e^{e}\left(1-\frac e 2 x+\frac{11e}{24}x^2+\frac{e^2}{8}x^2+o(x^2)\right)-e^e\left(1-\frac e 2 x+\frac e3x^2+\frac {e^2}{8}x^2+o(x^2)\right)}{x^2}=$$

$$=\frac{\frac{11e^{e+1}}{24}x^2-\frac{e^{e+1}}{3}x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{\frac{e^{e+1}}{8}x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{e^{e+1}}{8}+o(1)\to \frac{e^{e+1}}{8}$$

Comment: I somehow managed to find a way to avoid the calculation of Taylor series coefficients. +1 for typing all that correctly (I hope).

Answer (score 3):

You may approach
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\exp\exp\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}-\exp\left(e\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}\right)}{x^2}$$
by composition of Maclaurin series. We have
$$ \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O(x^3) $$
$$ \exp\left(\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}\right)=e-\frac{e}{2}x+\frac{11e}{24} x^2+O(x^3) $$
$$ \exp\left(e\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}\right)=e^e-\frac{1}{2}e^{e+1}x+\frac{1}{24}e^{e+1}(8+3e)x^2+O(x^3) $$
$$ \exp\exp\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}=e^e-\frac{1}{2}e^{e+1}x+\frac{1}{24}e^{e+1}(11+3e)x^2+O(x^3) $$
hence the wanted limit equals $\frac{1}{8}e^{e+1}$.